# What is the horizontal space of trivial hermitian line bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $L=M\times\Bbb C$ is a trivial holomorphic line bundle on a complex manifold $M$, and suppose there is a Hermitian fibre metric $h$ on $L$.

> **Question:** What is the horizontal space of $T_{(p,z)}L$ with respect to the canonical connection on $L$.

I am a bit mixed up with all the definitions there are. Here the canonical connection is given by a connection 1-form, but we need to translate this into a splitting of the tangent space into horizontal and vertical space. There is clearly an obvious splitting of $T_{(p,z)}L$ and I am wondering if this is just that:

> We have $T_{(p,z)}L=T_{(p,z)}(M\times\Bbb C)=T_pM\oplus\Bbb C$. Is that the desired splitting?

Comment: Yes, it should be the obvious horizontal subspace you get from the product structure. The horizontal subspace is the kernel of the Ehresmann connection form on $L$ - assuming this is the kind of "connection 1-form" you're talking about, this should be straightforward.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis What weird about this is that it does not depend on the metric $h$. This is suspicious, isn't it?

Comment: I assumed by "canonical connection" you meant the one you get from the product structure, which has nothing to do with the metric. In general a fiber metric alone is not enough to induce a unique compatible connection. I don't think $h$ is relevant here.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis A hermitian metric on a holomorphic vector bundle does define a unique compatible connection: see Huybrechts Proposition 4.2.14.

Comment: Clearly I extrapolate my real knowledge too far into this foreign land of complexification. I guess the answer is then "no, that's the wrong kind of horizontal" unless the metric is constant in the product coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z$ be the standard vertical coordinate on $L$ so that we can write $h = \rho\ dz \otimes \overline{dz}$ for some real function $\rho$ on $M$. The connection induced by $h$ satisfies $\nabla h = 0$, so plugging in the standard basis we get $$d \rho =\nabla (h(\partial_z, \bar\partial_z)) =h(\nabla \partial_z,\bar\partial_z) + h(\partial_z, \nabla\bar\partial_z).$$

From what I can gather, the compatibility condition with the complex structure is that the $(0,1)$-component of $\nabla$ is just $\bar \partial$. This means that the second term above vanishes, and the first is just $\rho \omega$ for $\omega$ the single 1-form associated to the holomorphic frame $\{\partial_z\}$ for $L$. Thus we can write $\omega = d \log \rho$, and the general expression for the connection is just $$\nabla s = d s + s\ d \log \rho.$$

Thus in order for a section $s$ to be $\nabla$-parallel we require $ds = -s\ d \log \rho$, so the horizontal subspace of $T_{(p,z)} L \simeq T_p M \oplus \Bbb C$ is $$\{(v,w) \in T_pM \oplus \Bbb C : w = -z\ d(\log \rho)(v)\}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! But shouldn't it be $\omega=\partial\log\rho$? We have $\omega=\rho^{-1}\partial\rho=\partial\log\rho$, right?

Comment: @Cod: you're probably right - check my argument in the second paragraph. I'm guessing that term doesn't just vanish and that you instead need to take the holomorphic part for things to simplify.